# can not able to change ip address with domain name

Tags: wordpress, dns, ip

I want to replace my ip address with my already bought domain name. How can I do so?

As I'm using amazon EC2 Instance. I changed record of my ROUTE S2 to point to my ip. When I open my website, it's opening but when I click on any menu, domain name changed to IP again.

I tried changing my wordpress index.php file. I changes IP address with my domain name. It's not solving the issue..

Any Solution Friends?

Comment: What do you mean you want to 'move your IP address'? IP addresses in general *cant* be moved. Can you better explain exactly what you have now, and what your trying to do. You should see how to write a [mcve]

Comment: @user3788685 Hope it's clear now!

Answer (score 0):

Yash,

You must access the domain's panel and look at change DNS things (you will need to know your nameservers for this ~~ contact your hosting provider). Or you can simply try to edit the DNS records, in specifically the A one, pointing to your hosting IP address.

If you have any doubt else, please let me know.

Comment: I did that. It's working only on my homepage. when I click on other menu, domain name will be replaced by IP.